# Custom formLogin() in Spring security returns a (type=Forbidden, status=403)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I've Setup a Spring boot app using dependencies of Spring Security and Spring Web. 
I use for this example inMemoryAuthentication().
I setup 3 html pages and placed them in the Static folder (I'm not using Thymeleaf or JSP pages just plain html).

When I use default formLogin() , and run the app , I get the default login page of spring security , once I type user and password I'm able to get the destined page dash.html as expected.

When I use a customized formLogin() , run the app , I get status 403 type Forbidden:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Dec 12 10:10:14 IST 2019 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Forbidden, status=403).
>
> Forbidden

I searched in StackOverflow , also searched in the link below , but didn't see any solution
(In the link it uses Thymeleaf , whereas I'm using HTML pages placed in the resources/static folder)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#creating-a-login-view

Did someone have this issue also ?
**Please Advise,**

Regards,
Shalem

**Related Data and Code:**

1. I'm Using Spring boot 2.1.3
2. JAVA8
3. Project folders layout in the linked image: [folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB4PA.png)

**I setup Spring Security code as follows:**

```
package com.rc1.conig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("shalem")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("12"))
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/dash/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/mylogin")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

**- Controllers Code :**

```
package com.rc1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class DashController {

    @RequestMapping("/dash")
    public String getDashboard() {
        return "dash.html";
    }
}


package com.rc1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/mylogin")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "login-page.html";
    }
}
```

*** HTML Pages:**

```
<!-- index.html page -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <h3>
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/dash">dashboard</a>
    </h3>
</body>
</html>


<!-- Customized login-page.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>mylogin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/mylogin" method="post">
        <p>
            user: <input type="text" name="user">
        </p>
        <p>
            pass :<input type="password" name="password">
        </p>
        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<!-- dash.html page -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>dashboard receieved</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's your springboot main application? It should place at root package above than other classes.

Comment: My Spring Boot main application is in the root package ** (com.rc1) ** , all other classes are in sub packages to root , Controllers (in com.rc1.controller) , SecurityConfig (in com.rc1.config)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom login page, then you should specify where username and password submitted to. 
So, just change here,

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/dash/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/mylogin")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage")
        .permitAll();
}
```

After that, any anonymous user hit any authenticated url, then redirect to

> /mylogin

after that user put username and password then that username and password submitted to

> /perform_login

If credential are valid then redirect to

> /homepage

otherwise go back to

> /mylogin